# ImageButton over an ImageView in TableLayout

Tags: android, imageview, tablelayout

I'm writing an application for Android and i have difficulties with the TableLayout. So I'd like to put an ImageView over an ImageButton in a row,but when i put them in the same row these are next to each other even if I set alligment.
I copy my xml code:

```
  <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:stretchColumns="0"
    tools:context="hu.szada.examplefortable.MainActivity" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ajandekboltbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ajandekbolt" />
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/pipalista"/>

    </TableRow>

  </TableLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```

If anyone has an idea how to do that please response!

Comment: You didn't describe your problem clearly

Comment: Try to put RelativeLayout inside TableRow, and then put ImageView and ImageButton in Relative Layout

Comment: Thank you very much!  It works fine! :)